# Component flickering at runtime design winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to develop a win form application which allows updating the design at run time. So I add a generic design form  using Designer Host and DesignSurface to add Root component and other components from the caller form, then I can change the locations and properties of components and update back to the caller form. It works fine if I add the design form on the same project with other forms. Now I want to split the design form to a separate project (Windows Forms Control Library) so I can pack this design form and other design classes to a DLL and the main project can have a reference to this DLL. However, the design form starts flickering when I add root components and other components. I have tried to add double buffering to design form but this issue cannot be solved. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: "I want to develop a win form application which allows updating the design at run time"....this is a very odd requirement. What are you trying to achieve with this idea?

Comment: You can use it to speedup prototyping, or developing simple applications for example.

Comment: Personally I think it will cause you more problems than it solves, but good luck.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Visual studio 2019 from 16.6 to 16.7.2, this issue has been solved. It seems that some memory management has been improved but i am not so sure.